# AWS API gateway + lambda. DNS lookup fails for long time after modifications

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws

1. I have an API running with API gateway + lambda and deployed with terraform
2. It runs in a private vpc and is only reachable from within my network
3. When I make a modification to the terraform, the DNS lookup of my endpoint fails.
4. After 1-2 hours the DNS lookup starts to work again with no change from me. But it takes ages
5. The output from my terraform apply stage look something like this

   ```
   aws_s3_bucket_object.file_upload: Modifying... [id=api.zip]
   aws_s3_bucket_object.file_upload: Modifications complete after 2s [id=api.zip]
   module.lambda["file_1"].aws_lambda_function.function: Modifying... [id=file1]
   module.lambda["file_2"].aws_lambda_function.function: Modifying... [id=file1]
   module.lambda["file_1"].aws_lambda_function.function: Modifications complete after 7s [id=file1]
   module.lambda["file_2"].aws_lambda_function.function: Modifications complete after 8s [id=file1]
   aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api: Modifying... [id=***********]
   aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api: Modifications complete after 1s [id=*******]
   aws_api_gateway_deployment.api_deployment: Creating...
   aws_api_gateway_deployment.api_deployment: Creation complete after 1s [id=*****]
   aws_api_gateway_stage.v1: Modifying... [id=*****]
   aws_api_gateway_stage.v1: Modifications complete after 0s [id=*****]
   aws_api_gateway_deployment.api_deployment (deposed object *****): Destroying... [id=*****]
   aws_api_gateway_deployment.api_deployment: Destruction complete after 0s
   ```

If anyone has any tips or knows why my DNS lookup keeps going down for hours at a time, I'd greatly appreciate it

Comment: Are you setting the TTL value for the record maybe?

Comment: Initially we thought it was the TTL. But seems now that it's a bug in aws, which they have acknowledged but won't fix